# Regex match JNDI name as long as line isn't commented out

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to scan java files and pull out JNDI names using regex. I have the string match working as follows:

```
((?<=("))java:/jms/.+(?=\"))
```

But I want to exclude commented lines -- i.e. lines matching:

```
^ *//
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to merge the two into a single expression.

For example, from the following lines:

@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/Queue-good"),
//@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/Queue-bad"),

I would like the return to be: java:/jms/Queue-good

I am doing this from a python script.

Comment: Add the comments as a conditional negative look-behind at the beginning of your expression.

Comment: Post a real example of the commented lines you want to exclude (short).

Comment: In the following string...
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/Queue-good"),
//@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "java:/jms/Queue-bad"),

I want the return to be:

java:/jms/Queue-good

Comment: Ok, so how about this: `.*?(?<!^//)"(java:/jms/.+)"` (not tested). Your desired result is the first (and only) captured group

Comment: Nope... this doesn't successfully avoid comments AND matches the full line, not just he JNDI